# How would I generating a Sox Synthesized sound similar to an alarm bell

Tags: alarm, sox, synthesizer

I am trying to generate a sound using the sox package synth feature, alarm 1: https://soundcloud.com/xekons/a1-1 and alarm 2: https://soundcloud.com/xekons/a2-1

its possible to create some interesting sounds:

```
play -q -n synth 0.2 sine 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 triangle 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 square 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 pluck 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 pluck C5 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 sawtooth 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 trapezium 480 vol 0.2
play -q -n synth 0.2 exp 480 vol 0.2
```

Here is a very elaborate one I found online:

```
play -n synth pl G2 pl B2 pl D3 pl G3 pl D4 pl G4 delay 0 .05 .1 .15 .2 .25 remix - fade 0 4 .1 norm -1
```

To listen to the alarm wave file it seems like its a decreasing volume, but maybe also frequency?

I tried this:

```
play -q -n synth 0.6 triangle 1500-1300 vol 0.2
```

which changes the frequency, but beyond that it sounds nothing like the bell lol. Also not looking for a close match, just something sounding somewhat similar to the bell in those wav files I linked.

The sox synthesized sound will be used in the python script that I am writing, and will go off under certain conditions. I plan to make the entire project I am working on opensource once I polish it up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

When listening to the 'alarm' sound, you hear a *constant* frequency, with the volume gradually going down. The decreasing volume is easily achieved by fading out.

```
play -n synth 3 sin 960 fade l 0 3 2.8
```

Explanation:

- `synth 3`: take plenty of time (here: 3 seconds) to allow `fade` to slowly decrease the volume. If the result turns out to be too long, then you can always `trim` afterwards, for example if you want to repeat the sound every second.
- `sin 960`: any wave form or frequency will do. For a bell, sine makes most sense.
- `fade l`: fade, logarithmic. I think that is the most 'natural' one for a bell.
- `0`: no fade-in.
- `3 2.8`: stay at full volume for 0.2 seconds, then fade out to silence during the remaining 2.8 seconds.

To make the bell toll multiple times, trim and repeat.

```
play -n synth 3 sin 960 fade l 0 3 2.8 trim 0 1 repeat 2
```

For a richer sound, play around with frequency modulation.
For example, this already sounds a bit more like the sample alarm:

```
play -n synth 3 sin 960 synth 3 sin fmod 1920 fade l 0 3 2.8 trim 0 1 repeat 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to synthesize the sounds, I really wish I understood the synthesizer better.

for now I am just playing the files directly from my python script, here is a small snippet:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial, time, sox, psycopg2

tfm = sox.Transformer()  #initialize sox playback

tfm.preview("/wav/a2.wav") #play alarm 2 wav file
```

If anyone can synthesize any sounds remotely similar to the ones I linked, please do post, and I will update this to mark your answer as the correct one. THANK YOU!